# alfresco share site dashboard dashlets

Tags: alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have created a site dashboard which has 3 dashlets. The data required by 3 dashlets and displaying in different views.

Currently I am using rest api call using "connector.get" inside webscript1.get.js,webscript2.get.js and webscript3.get.js files. Repeatedly calling in all three dashlets.

My question is, can I call it once and share the object with all three dashlets? I tried doing this with surf root objects, but those objects are immutable. Please can any one help?

Comment: I don't think, you can do that. Dashlets work independently, if you created some components with Aikau, then you can try with the Publication-subscription mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

In this case what you can do is, save the response of your ajax call in one global javascript variable.When first time you are calling an api, it will call the api and then set the response of it to a global javascript variable.

In other dashlets you can check whether this variable is null or not, If not null you can use the data.